# get logon credentials in domain

Tags: c#, dns, get

I want to get network domain credentials of the user by my code.

```
string user = Environment.UserName;
string userName = System.Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent().Name;
```

I can get NAME with above samples, but I need password too. Is It possible to get password?

My purpose: I want to use the  user's domain login credentials in my code, so the user do not have to login again to my windows app..., but i have to use login credentials for SoapHeader authentication...

Regards...

Comment: `Is It possible to get password?` No.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See [this thread](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/36e1bcfa-a46a-47a8-8b21-78357efe866b/how-to-get-windows-login-credentials-using-cnet?forum=netfxbcl).

That's, what you have already:

> You can get the current identity of the user under which the current
>   thread is running (not necessarily the logged in user) using
>   **WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent()**.  Alternatively you can get the logged in
>   user name via the **Environment.UserName** property.  It is not guaranteed
>   to be the user running the current process however.

Is it possible to retrieve the password? No, the password isn't stored in Windows:

> There is no Windows API to get a user's password as **passwords aren't
>   stored in Windows**.  Instead Windows stores a one-way hashed version.

Hope it helps!

**EDIT: Documentation:** Here are the associated docs to [GetCurrent()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sfs49sw0%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) and the returning value [WindowsIdentity](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.principal.windowsidentity%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).